# Angular filtering by a numerical expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to build a filter in angular that takes a mathematical expression, i am not very well versed in angular or javascript but i get things done, as far as i am concerned for what i need to write my own parser then evaluate the expression

```
//bigger than                 x>y 
//smaller than                x<y 
//equal                       x=y 
//not equal                   x!=y
//bigger than or equal        x>!
//smaller than or equal       x<=y
// x mod y = 0 divisable by   x%y=0
//Is factorial of x           !x=y
//|| &&
```

i thought of writing my own parser which simply splits the expression by || and && and then evaluates the left and right part, i did something similar in c#, so do i have to write the parser from scratch or such things already exist in angular filter concepts?

i will be using this in my angular table directive for numerical columns, i explored the already existing projects and there was only string based filtering and non dynamic numerical filtering

to clear things up i wrote a simple table directive
[image]

currently it filters based on string using the default angular filter, and i want to do numerical filtering based on mathematical expressions, but i want to write one additional filter that receives  the expression and evaluates it

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what do u want to filter. Could you please show us some example of what u want to filter and the result. Thx

Comment: @davs i added more details :)

Comment: the answer is yes, you need to write a parser for your language. this is not specific to angular.

Comment: @akonsu or use javascript expressions then use eval?

Comment: using `eval` might be not secure. but I cannot think of any exploit right now. maybe this is irrational. :)

Comment: I wonder how angular does this. you know, for the expressions in angular attributes.

Comment: they have `$parse` service. maybe you can check out the code.

Comment: @akonsu i found this lovely thing http://jsep.from.so/